# VLAN with Docker

Tags: docker, proxy, vlan

I need to create a pool of proxies with public ips. I have multiples ips link to my server.

I'm trying a simple case for the moment. A socks5 proxy with docker.

```
docker run -p 1080:1080 serjs/go-socks5-proxy
```

That ... doesn't work

```
curl -x socks5://serverip:1080 google.fr
```

```
 2023/06/23 16:10:01 Start listening proxy service on port 1080
 2023/06/23 16:10:02 [INFO] socks: Connection from allowed IP address: x.x.x.x
 2023/06/23 16:10:02 [ERR] socks: Failed to handle request: Connect to 127.0.0.1:80 failed: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You **cannot** combine `-p` and `--net=host`. Either you are mapping host ports to container ports (`-p`), or you are simply running in the host network namespace and port mapping is unnecessary (`--net=host`). Pick one.

Comment: I updated the informations. This change anything to the problem :)

Comment: The error `dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused` doesn't make sense unless you have an `/etc/hosts` entry mapping `google.fr` to `127.0.0.1`.